# Prompt for details during a canvas app install

Tags: app, canvas

I'm trying to decipher how to best integrate our SaaS app with SF and a canvas app seems to be the best choice.  However, I'm struggling with how how to do this and the SF documentation isn't helping.  Here's what I'm hoping to do:

- Have an app available for our customers to install.
- When the app is installed, prompt for an "activation code", which will be used for a custom re-direct.
- When the user launches the app, it opens a page which does the re-directs to the appropriate sub-domain (i.e. the activation code) on our servers.

I should note that I do have OAuth authentication working outside of Canvas, so we're good as far as authorization is concerned.  Realistically I just need the sub-domain at install time and have it stored for the client so that they can be re-directed properly.  Being able to reset this code would be the cherry on top.  Can anyone provide any guidance on where I should be focusing my efforts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can dynamically change the Canvas apps URL (or callback URL for OAuth). You could store the required activation code in a custom setting and then read it out via the API when they hit your landing page. The landing page would validate the activation code and redirect to the required sub-domain. Use a [Custom Link](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=creating_packages.htm&siteLang=en_US) on the managed package that installs the app to prompt for the activation code.

Comment: This should work...  All I need to do is really start the re-direct process from a page, or at least be able to pass in the activation code to our server in some way to kick off the process.  The OAuth callback log is common across our clients, so I'm okay with that.  Thanks, I'll give this a shot.